# How do I make a cart notification in AngularJs 1.5?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a project for school and got stuck.
I made a shopping cart in Angular, but when I add an item the cart notification of the cart icon ([Cart Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxYmm.png)) doesn't update unless I refresh the page.

cart.service.js

```
export default class Cart {

  constructor(AppConstants, $http) {
    'ngInject';

    this._AppConstants = AppConstants;
    this._$http = $http;
  }

  getCart() {
    return this._$http({
      url: this._AppConstants.api + '/cart',
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(
      (res) => {
        return res.data;
      }
    );
  }

  add(cover) {
    return this._$http({
      url: this._AppConstants.api + '/cart',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        cover: cover
      }
    }).then(
      (res) => {
        return res.data;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

cart.component.js

```
class CartCtrl {
  constructor(Cart, $scope) {
    'ngInject';

    Cart.getCart().then((res) => { this._qty = res.qty < 9 ? res.qty : 9 });
  }
}

let Cart = {
  controller: CartCtrl,
  templateUrl: 'components/cart.html'
};

export default Cart;
```

cart.html

```
<a ng-href="/#/cart"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"><span class="badge">{{$ctrl._qty}}</span></span></a>
```

header.html

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="pull-right">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li><cart></cart></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: What is your question? Why do you think it should refresh, given the code you posted? Read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope, and in particlular the doc of $on and $broadcast.

Comment: Try using `$scope.$apply()` after you insert that new item in your cart.

Comment: Are you have two controllers one is for header and one is for cart ?
Your data passing for $ctrl._qty is problematic.

Could you please share the plunker or jsfiddel or other link.